# Unable to start Opentext Process Platform installed in a distributed computer

Tags: business-process-management, cordys-opentext

In Windows, Opentext Process Platform is unable to start in the
distributed computer when the primary and distributed computers are in
different subnets.

I have tried to `traceout` and both the Subnets are fine. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `ttl` property in all computers(primary and distributed):

a. Go to Management Console > Properties.

b. Add the property: `bus.network.udp.ttl = <no of hops>`.

c. Then Restart Process Platform on all the computers.